# Change File size limit for Symfony2 DomCrawler or Goutte

Tags: php, symfony, web-crawler, domcrawler

I am using [Goutte v2.0.4](https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/Goutte) which is a wrapper for [Symfony2 DomCrawler](http://symfony.com/doc/any/components/dom_crawler.html). I have the html files locally stored. Some of them are below 10MB; I have crawled those files successfully.

Other files are above 30MB. These are not getting crawled. This may be a file size issue. 
All files have similar formatting.
So what's wrong? How to crawl big sized files?

Comment: Do you mean your link discoverer is not finding large files at all, or that Goutte is attempting them and fails with an error? You can add a HTTP subscriber to Goutte to log what it tries and what it fails, so if you don't already have that, it would be a good addition.

Comment: It tries and stops without showing any error. I didn't knew about HTTP subscriber, I'll look into that.  v2.0.4

Comment: Do you receive any errors when you attempt to parse files >10 Mb? If so what is the error message that you receive?